# Count the Number of String Matches

Tags: java, regex, string, match

I want to get the smallest match of strings in the list. Though I'm successful doing so but the problem is i want to count that how many match counts have been made so:

```
List<String> mylist=new LinkedList<String>();
Set<String> result=new LinkedHashSet<String>();
mylist.add("interpreter");
mylist.add("interprete");
mylist.add("interpret");

mylist.add("developed");
mylist.add("develops");
mylist.add("develop");
mylist.add("interpret");


String small="";
Collections.sort(mylist);
Collections.reverse(mylist);

for(int i=0;i<mylist.size();i++)
{

  small=mylist.get(i);

   for(int j=i;j<mylist.size();j++)
   {
    if(small.contains(mylist.get(j)))
    {
        small=mylist.get(j);
    }
   }
   result.add(small);
}
for (String string : result) {
   System.out.println(string);
}
```

So that the output should be:

```
interpret=4
develop=4
```

Problem occurs with the following code i am trying:

```
List<String> mylist=new LinkedList<String>();
Set<String> result=new LinkedHashSet<String>();
mylist.add("interpreter");
mylist.add("interprete");
mylist.add("interpret");

mylist.add("developed");
mylist.add("develops");
mylist.add("develop");
mylist.add("interpret");
mylist.add("crawler");
mylist.add("crawl");
mylist.add("mobile");
mylist.add("mob");
mylist.add("juni");
mylist.add("junis");

Collections.sort(mylist);
Collections.reverse(mylist);

String small="";
int c=0;

for(int i=0;i<mylist.size();i++)
{
    c+=1;
    small=mylist.get(i);
    for(int j=i;j<mylist.size();j++)
    {
        if(small.contains(mylist.get(j)))
            {
                small=mylist.get(j);
                c+=1;
            }
    }
    result.add(small);

}
for (String string : result) {
    System.out.println(string+"="+c);
}
```

can somebody help me please!

Comment: On a side note, such problems are best solved using something called a suffix tree or a Trie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting @jambriz's answer in your code:

1.Use a HashMap

```
HashMap<String, Integer> result= new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
```

2.Instead of `result.add(small);` now, add the value in hashmap only if the value is new or the count is less than the previous count. Also, set `c=0` here

```
if (!result.containsKey(small) || result.get(small) < c)
    result.put(small, c);
c = 0;
```

3.At Last print your results:

```
for (String key : result.keySet())
    System.out.println(key + ": " + result.get(key));
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, first of all, your first code would print

```
interpret
develop
```

because you aren´t counting anything
and it should be

```
interpret=4
develop=3
```

anyway.

The second block only has one counter 'c'. You should have one counter per each found word.
I would suggest using a Map of Strings and Integers. When the String is nonexistent you put(small,1) and when it exists you get the Integer and add one to it.
Let us know if that worked

(btw, there's no regex in your code, it shouldn't be tagged as such)

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] smallestStrings; //this has "interpret", "develop"

int[] matches = new int[smallestStrings.length];

for (int i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
    matches[i] = 0;
    for (String s : mylist) if (s.contains(smallestStrings[i])) matches[i]++;
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to give !