# How to stop repeated print in java

Tags: java, for-loop

I am printing items from an ArrayList with this code:

```
for(int i2 = 0; i2 < a.size(); i2++)
    {
        word2 = a.get(i2);
        for(int j2 = 0; j2 < a.size(); j2++)
        {
            if(word2.equals(a.get(j2)))
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        if(counter!=0)
        {
            System.out.println(word2 + " : " + counter);
        }
        counter = 0;
    }
```

When I print I don't want to print out the duplicates. As it is now, it will print

```
Alphabet : 3
Alright : 3
Apple : 3
Alphabet : 3
Alright : 3
Apple : 3
Alphabet : 3
Alright : 3
Apple : 3
```

I only want it to print

```
Alphabet : 3
Alright : 3
Apple : 3
```

How do I make it not print the duplicates? I have to use ArrayList for the assignment

Comment: use a `Set` instead of a `List`

Comment: @JarrodRoberson A set would remove duplicates from the list, thus losing information about word counts.

Comment: You could take some help from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22412035/count-the-number-of-string-matches/22412699

Comment: The the appropriate collection is a `Multimap`

Comment: @JarrodRoberson A `Multiset` would be more appropriate (the `Multimap` would require some arbitrary value objects), but same idea. The words could be inserted into, e.g., Guava's [`Multiset`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release02/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html), then `count()` will return the word count given a word. You should post an example as an answer, it would be another nice clean approach.

Answer (score 2):

Another option, while performance is not the greatest (although it will be sufficient for your application, and has similar performance characteristics to your current code), is to create a temporary `Set` to hold a list of unique words, then use [`Collections.frequency()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency%28java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.Object%29) to count the occurrences in the original list, e.g. with your `ArrayList<String> a`:

```
Set<String> unique = new HashSet<String>(a);

for (String word : unique)
    System.out.println(word + " : " + Collections.frequency(a, word));
```

Or even just:

```
for (String word : new HashSet<String>(a))
    System.out.println(word + " : " + Collections.frequency(a, word));
```

The benefit here is short and clear code.

You can use a [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) if you want to print the words in alphabetical order, or a [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) if you want to print them in the order of first occurrence.

As an aside, the above does not store the counts for later use, which your original code does not do either. However, if you wanted to do this, it's trivial to store the results in a map:

```
Map<String,Integer> wordCounts = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

for (String word : new HashSet<String>(a))
    wordCounts.put(word, Collections.frequency(a, word));

// wordCounts now contains a map of strings -> counts.
```

Comment: Nice! I wasn't aware of this `Collections.frequency` method. How does it work? Are frequencies stored somewhere when objects are added? What is the time complexity of this method?

Comment: @BrianVanover I've added a documentation link. `frequency()` isn't optimized in any way, each call is O(n) on the size of the container; it simply iterates through the container and counts elements that equal the specified object as per `equals()`. It is similar to the OP's original implementation. This technique may not be suitable for huge word sets, but for smaller sets in simple applications, performance is generally acceptable.

Comment: The entire thing is O(mn), where m = number of unique words and n = total number of words; worst case O(n^2) when no words are repeated, best case O(n) when all words are the same.

Comment: Thanks. I'm confused about iterating through the container. Maybe I need more clarification on the underlying process for Sets. Won't duplicates not be added to the Set, so there would be no reference to the duplicates to count?

Comment: @BrianVanover Note that `Collections.frequency(a, word)` counts the frequency in the *original* `ArrayList a`, rather than in the set.

Comment: Got it! Thanks. +1 for concise answer and thorough explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `TreeMap<String, Integer>` to track word counts

```
SortedMap<String, Integer> wordFrequencyMap = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();

for (String str : a) {
  if (wordFrequencyMap.containsKey(str)) {
    int strFreq = Integer.intValue(wordFrequencyMap.get(str));
    strFreq++;
    wordFrequencyMap.put(str, new Integer(strFreq));
  }
  else {
    wordFrequencyMap.put(str, new Integer(1));
  }
}

for (String word : wordFrequencyMap.keySet()) {
  System.out.println(word + " : " + wordFrequencyMap.get(word));
}
```

This data structure will not allow duplicates and it will count the occurrence of each word with only having to traverse the list one time. Since you are using a `TreeMap` with `String` keys, it will print the keys in alphabetical order when iterating

Comment: +1 Adding to this: In more performance limited environments, one common optimization with this is to define a custom mutable counter class that wraps a primitive `int`, so that the count can be updated without creating a `new Integer`. There is also `MutableInt` in Apache Commons.

Answer (score 0):

Another Java-8 stream alternative:

This creates a map at `collect` step: the key is the word (because `Function.identity()` returns every word) and the value is the frequency (because  `Collectors.counting()` returns every word frequency).
And the `forEach` step just prints every entry `"<word>: <word-frequency>"`

```
a.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
               Function.identity(),
               Collectors.counting()))
          .forEach((word, frequency) -> System.out.println(word+": "+frequency));
```